# Cant pass a variable from PHP to bash

Tags: php, bash, variables

Im trying to pass a variable from php to bash, but im having problems.

Here is a snippet of the **PHP** code.

```
<?php
$shopidX = escapeshellarg('$shop_id');
exec("~/bin/notaproblem $shopidX");
<?
```

Here is where the variable is defined in **bash**.

```
shopidX=$1
```

Now the variable does not work. I have tried hardcoding the variable in the bash script (e.x)

```
shopidX=89234796743682446811473645238461264123465243614537285417254237645712345768235472364536217481238431654187
```

And it does work. The `$shop_id` is also 100% defined in PHP. What's the problem?

Comment: Why are you using single quotes? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: Yeah all you're doing is executing `~/bin/notaproblem $shopidX`

Answer (score 1):

Wrong quotes:

```
$shopidX = escapeshellarg('$shop_id');
                          ^--------^
```

`'`-quotes do NOT interpolate variables:

```
$foo = 'bar;
echo '$foo'; // outputs $, f, o, o
echo "$foo"; // outputs b, a, r
```

You're sending `$`, `s`, `h`, etc.. to the shell, not the contents of the variable.

In fact, you don't need quotes AT ALL

```
$shopidX = escapeshellarg($shop_id);
```

Comment: Impossible. `'`-quoted strings have never allowed variables.

Answer (score 0):

HTML code:

```
<html>
<form>
<input name="name">
</form>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$output = shell_exec("C:/xampp/folder/scriptname.sh $name");
?>
```

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
name=$1
echo name=${name:-$1}
```